# How does this Fibonacci code run with channels and go routines?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, go, fibonacci

There is this website called [rosetta code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Go) that has algorithms in all languages so you can learn and compare when learning new languages.

Here I saw that one of the solutions for go lang is pretty interesting but I don't fully understand it.

```golang
func fib(c chan int) {
    a, b := 0, 1
    for {
        c <- a
        a, b = b, a+b
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go fib(c)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }
}
```

Here are some of my doubts

How does the infinite for loop know when to stop?
How does the c channel communicate this?
What is the logical sequence between the func calls?

Thanks for the help kind strangers.

Comment: The infinite loop never terminates. The loop continues until `main` returns and the program exits. However, because the channel `c` is unbuffered, this will not lead to infinite iterations of the for loop. It should iterate only 11 times since `main` reads from `c` 10 times. I would suggest to look into the difference between unbuffered and buffered Goroutines to understand this.

Comment: Does this mean that the channel is creating a thread which continues running and giving values to the main 10 times?

Comment: Sorry, unbuffered and buffered *channels* is what I meant to say. That is a typo in my comment. The only time in this program where a new Goroutine is created is the `go fib(c)` statement. The significance of the channel type is that an unbuffered channel will block on writes (such as `c <- a`) until another Goroutine reads from the same channel. Since main only reads 10 times, the 11th write to `c` will block until the program exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does the infinite for loop know when to stop?

As you said: This is an infinite loop and doesn't stop at all (as long as the program is running).

> How does the c channel communicate this?

The channel c doesn't communicate stopping the for loop at all, the loop is not stopped. The sole purpose of c is to deliver the next number in the sequence from the calculation site (the infinite for loop) to the usage site (the print loop).

> What is the logical sequence between the func calls?

`go fib(c)` starts fib as a goroutine. This is the one and only function call (*) ever happening in your code. Once `go fib(c)` has happened you have to concurrent things running: 1. The main function which will print 10 times and 2. fib(c) which does the computation.

The interesting stuff -- the synchronization between main() and fib(c) -- happens when main executes `<-c` and ("in the same moment") fib executes `c <- a`. Both functions, main and fib work until they both reach those lines. Once both are "at that line", both will happen "at the same time": fib will write/send to c and main consumes/receives from c "simultaneous". Afterwards both functions main and fib continue independently.

Once main is done the program finishes (this also "stops" fib's infinite loop).

(*) for the nitpickers: besides the fmt.Printf and make call which are irrelevant for understanding of this code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, from what you said it looks like a threaded problem that has a really smart mutex lock implementation and abstraction.